# Python regex with newlines doesn't match

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

and in a Python program I am searching for

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

The program is

```
import re

file = open("blah.log","r")
file_contents = file.read()

pattern='''Line1
Line2 
Line3'''

matchObj = re.search(pattern, file_contents, re.M|re.I)
if matchObj:
   print matchObj.group(0)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

However, it shows no match even the pattern is in the file.

But if the

```
file_contents = '''Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4''' # not reading from the file
```

Now it matches with regex pattern.

What is the reason for this?

How can I make the program work with the reading the contents from the file?

Comment: What is actually in the file? Can you post a hex dump?

Comment: It works in my case. And why are you using Python 2?

Comment: I can see in the debug mode that, file contents are File1\r\nFile2\r\nFile3\r\nFile4 but the pattern contains File1\nFile2\nFile3

Comment: @Prajwal I was about to answer that. There's your answer then.

Comment: Can't I use that format then? Like triple quotes? What's the proper way to match in this case? @blhsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lines in your file are delimited by `'\r\n'`, the pattern you search for should account for that.

For convenience, you can still use triple quotes to initialize the string you want to search for, but then use the `str.replace()` method to replace all occurrences of `'\n'` with `'\r\n'`:

```
pattern='''Line1
Line2 
Line3'''.replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

Furthermore, if all you need is a substring match, you can use the `in` operator instead of the more costly regex match:

```
if pattern in file_contents:
   print pattern
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

New line character in a file can be '\n', '\r' or '\r\n'. It depends on OS. To be at safer side, try to match with all new line characters.

```
pattern='''Line1(\n|\r|\r\n)Line2(\n|\r|\r\n)Line3'''
```